# Vim: BufNewFile autocmd does not work when inside filetype plugin

Tags: java, vim, neovim, autocmd

Background story: I want vim to generate a public class declaration when editing new java files, so I wrote the following augroup:

```
augroup generate_public_class_declaration_upon_creation
    au!
    autocmd BufNewFile *.java execute "normal! ipublic class " . expand('%:t:r') . "\<CR>{}\<Left>\<CR>\<CR>\<Up>\<Tab>" | startinsert
augroup END
```

Which works fine when put in .vimrc, but no longer functions after being transferred to ftplugin/java.vim. I tried some other events e.g. BufWritePre, BufWinEnter inside java.vim and nothing goes wrong. What's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the time that snippet is executed from your ftplugin it is already too late for catching the `BufNewFile` event.

You can either leave it in your `vimrc`, where it is known to work, or modify it so that it can be executed from your ftplugin.

Here is a quick and dirty solution:

```
" in after/ftplugin/java.vim
if !(bufname()->filereadable())
    execute "normal! ipublic class " . expand('%:t:r') . "\<CR>{}\<Left>\<CR>\<CR>\<Up>\<Tab>" | startinsert!
endif
```

where we check if there is a file for the current buffer before inserting our skeleton.

Basically, when you do `:e foo.java` or `$ vim foo.java`, a buffer is created with the name `foo.java`, which is supposed to be the name of the associated file and can be retrieved with `:help bufname()`. If a file with that name doesn't exist, we check with `:help filereadable()`, we can insert the skeleton.

Note the `!` after `startinsert`: without it the insertion would happen before the `<Tab>`. See `:help :startinsert`.

Comment: I guess `!` should be put outside the brackets `if !(bufname()->filereadable())`?

Comment: No, it shouldn't.

Comment: I did the following tests:

`:echo !(bufname()->filereadable())` is evaluated to `0` in existing file and `1` in new files;

`:echo (!bufname()->filereadable())` is evaluated to `0` in both;

I dunno the reason behind but it seems putting it outside the brackets works for me.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the mess.